# Async/await endlessly works if nothing comes from websocket events

Tags: python, websocket, async-await

Could you help me with the logic of WebSockets and async/await?
When I subscribe to events with WebSockets I don't know when events come so I need some condition to exit from `while` but it endlessly works at this code `msg = json.loads(await sws_socket.recv())` because `await` always wait for something. But if nothing comes it can't again check condition and process endlessly work. So how to improve my logic?

```
async def collect_events(sws_socket):
    end_time = datetime.today() + timedelta(seconds=30)
    while datetime.today() < end_time:
        msg = json.loads(await sws_socket.recv())
        events.append(msg)

async def socket_events():
    async with websockets.connect(url) as ws:
        await ws.send(json.dumps(subscribe_event_model))

        task2 = asyncio.create_task(collect_events(sws_socket=ws))
        asyncio.create_task(send_message())
        await task2

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(socket_events())
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python websockets, how to setup connect timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54421029/python-websockets-how-to-setup-connect-timeout)

Comment: No, events come after I connect to the server and subscribe to events

Comment: Solution is the same, you set up timeout for async request just like described in the accepted answer.